# Can't migrate from Rails App to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, migration, pg

The error:

```
rake aborted!
Gem::LoadError: Specified 'postgresql' for database adapter, but the 
gem is not loaded. Add `gem 'pg'` to your Gemfile (and ensure its 
version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord).
```

My Gemfile includes:

```
group :production do
gem 'pg', '~> 0.18.4'
gem 'rails_12factor', '~> 0.0.3'
end
```

I've already updated the bundler using "--without production" and all, but still getting the same error...

Comment: try this `gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'` and bundle

Comment: Still not working. Part of the error says "Gem::LoadError: pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile.". But it's already there...

Comment: can u post yr gem file and make sure gemfile.lock is being create/update after bundle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add pg in gemfile

```
group :production do
   gem 'pg', '~> 0.21'
   gem 'rails_12factor'
end

#Terminal
>$ bundle install
>$ git add .
>$ git commit -m 'pg added'
>$ git push heroku master
```

Make sure Gemfile.lock updated and has `pg`.

Comment: It works when pushing to heroku, but not when I try migrating, using "heroku run rake db:migrate". Here's the error I get: "Gem::LoadError: pg is not part of the bundle. Add it to your Gemfile."

Comment: try, `heroku run bundle install`

Comment: Is't 1st time deployment into Heroku ? if yes, try `heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev` also

Comment: It's not my first time, I have some apps on there already. I've just ran the command you sent me but I'm still getting exactly the same error. Unbelievable.

Comment: did u check gemfile.lock file ? and make sure its not in .gitignore file.

Comment: Yes, I checked these as well. I restarted my text editor and my terminal, and for some reason I managed to migrate to Heroku. Thank you!

Comment: Glad, you've fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

> ensure its version is at the minimum required by ActiveRecord

I have just pushed it into Heroku for testing using pg version `0.20.0`

```
group :production do
  gem 'pg', '~> 0.20.0'
  gem 'rails_12factor'
end
```

Once you make this update in your group production of your Gemfile, ensure you run `bundle install --without production` (to update Gemfile.lock file), do a git add/commit cycle, then re-deploy to Heroku.

and then

```
heroku run rake db:migrate
```